Why does this Node.js script produce different output each time?
This script is from a Nodejs introducing book. This part is about the event loop of Javascript.
const sleep_st = (t) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, t));
const sleep_im = () => new Promise((r) => setImmediate(r));

(async () => {
    setImmediate(() => console.log(1));
    console.log(2);
    await sleep_st(0);
    setImmediate(() => console.log(3));
    console.log(4);
})();

The two possible outputs are "2 4 1 3" and "2 1 4 3".
I expect the outputs are always consistent.

I realize this is example code and kinda written in a way that should be deterministic in theory, but IRL why would you expect asynchronous calls to resolve in a particular order?

Similar to sleep_st, you can use a promise wrapping setImmediate and await it.  In this  example the output is always 1 2 3 4.  I faked setImmediate for the example since it doesn't exist in browsers.


const sleep_st = (t) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, t));
const sleep_im = () => new Promise((r) => setImmediate(r));

const setImmediate = arg => setTimeout(arg, 0);

const si = f => new Promise(r => setImmediate(() => {f();r();}));

(async () => {
    await si(() => console.log(1));
    console.log(2);
    await sleep_st(0);
    await si(() => console.log(3));
    console.log(4);
})();




The code produces a different order of numbers each time because of the interplay between the JavaScript event loop, microtasks, and macrotasks, which introduces non-deterministic behavior.
Order of Execution

The event loop processes all microtasks before moving to the next macrotask.
The order in which setImmediate tasks are processed depends on the environment and when they are added relative to the current event loop tick.

Step-by-Step Execution:

Start Execution:

setImmediate(() => console.log(1)): Schedules a macrotask to log 1.
console.log(2): Logs 2 synchronously.
await sleep_st(0): Schedules a macrotask (setTimeout with 0 delay) and pauses the function until it resolves.


Macrotask: sleep_st(0) Resolves:

After the macrotask completes, it resumes the async function.


Inside the Async Function:

setImmediate(() => console.log(3)): Schedules another macrotask.
console.log(4): Logs 4 synchronously.


Event Loop Execution:

The event loop processes the tasks in the following order:

Remaining macrotasks (e.g., setImmediate callbacks).
Microtasks scheduled during the previous phase.





Why the Order Changes:

setImmediate Timing:

The timing of setImmediate relative to setTimeout depends on the environment (Node.js handles them differently than browsers).
In some cases, setImmediate tasks can run before or after setTimeout with 0ms delay, depending on when they were scheduled.


Race Condition:

setImmediate and setTimeout (even with 0ms) can race to execute their callbacks.
The exact timing of setImmediate(() => console.log(1)) and setImmediate(() => console.log(3)) introduces variability.



